# Conglomerate in mathematical literature.

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, definition, education

I rememeber I downloaded a pdf in category theory and after talking about classes it defined something called conglomerates, but I can't remember what that is and wikipedia has no article on it.

---

If I remember correctly it brought up some kind of paradox and had to introduce conglomerates to solve it. My question is also if there exists a similar paradox that applies to conglomerates and creates even another object. Regards ;)

Comment: Maybe http://therisingsea.org/notes/FoundationsForCategoryTheory.pdf or [*Joy of Cats*](http://katmat.math.uni-bremen.de/acc/acc.pdf)?

Comment: Yes, precisely, thank you.

Comment: You are very welcome! Regards

Comment: @Amzoti I would recommend repackaging one or both of those as an answer so this is no longer on the unanswered list.

Comment: @MarkS.: I added those as an answer. Regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two wonderful resources:

- [*Foundations for Category Theory, by Daniel Murfet*](http://therisingsea.org/notes/FoundationsForCategoryTheory.pdf)
- [*Joy of Cats*](http://katmat.math.uni-bremen.de/acc/acc.pdf)

Comment: Wow - Branching out into Category Theory! +1

Comment: Do you have off for the Thanksgiving weekend, or so you need to go to work on Friday?